# How to create docx file and download it using PhpWord

Tags: codeigniter-3, phpword

Hi I always got error when trying to create docx file and I want to download it directly. My browser is stuck on `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`. I'm using CodeIgniter framework by the way. Here is the code.

```
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007;

class Test extends MY_Controller{
   public function create()
   {
      $phpWord = new PhpWord();
      $section = $phpWord->addSection();
      $section->addText('Hello World!');
      $file = 'HelloWorld.docx';
      header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
      header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
      header('Expires: 0');
      $xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
      $xmlWriter->save("php://output");
   }
}
```

This code is just taken from the example in the PhpWord docs, but somehow it doesn't work. No error just `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` on the browser. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours digging, I finally found the solution for my problem. The problem exists because it relates to temporary folder. So what I have to do is 1. setting the path where the file temporarily saved and 2. I have to tell Phpword that it should use that path to store generated file.

```
$path = './uploads/tmp'; // Set the temporary path

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setTempDir($path); // Tell Phpword where the temporary path is
```

So this is the complete code

```
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Writer\Word2007;

class Test extends MY_Controller{
   public function create()
   {
      $phpWord = new PhpWord();
      $section = $phpWord->addSection();
      $section->addText('Hello World!');

      $path = './uploads/tmp'; // Set the temporary path
      \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setTempDir($path); // Tell Phpword where the temporary path is

      $file = 'HelloWorld.docx';
      header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
      header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
      header('Expires: 0');
      $xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
      $xmlWriter->save("php://output");
   }
}
```

Hope it can help those who get the same problem